# Creating popups in Folium (Leaflet) for GeoJSON polygon layer

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

Looking through the Folium documentation I can't find how to add a popup to a polygon GeoJSON layer in Folium. Looking through the Leaflet documentation it seems like its possible, but I don't know how to translate the JavaScript to Python. Below is a snippet of the code I'm using to render the map.

```py
stand_boundary = folium.GeoJson(stands_gdf, name='Stands')
```

The `stands_gdf` variable is a GeoJSON read into a `GeoDataFrame`.

Comment: Any update or solution?

Answer (score 0):

## List all columns except 'geometry' culumn of your GeoDataframe and create a popup with these fields

fields = [ column for column in stand_boundary.columns if column not in stand_boundary.select_dtypes('geometry')]

m = folium.Map(tiles='stamentoner')

folium.GeoJson(stand_boundary,
popup = folium.GeoJsonPopup(fields = fields)).add_to(m)